# How to get a dynamic dropdown with an ACF Relationship field

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, html-select, advanced-custom-fields

My website lists courses and course providers. I'm using ACF relationship to assign the providers to each course. **both courses and course providers are custom post types** I have a contact form for each single course page and I need to send the enquiry to the selected course provider from a dropdown. What I'm trying to do is to have a dynamic field where, once a provider has been selected, fetch their email (assigned as a acf field) into another form field and submit the form to that specific email. I'm getting both the list of assigned providers and their emails in following code.

```
               <select name="supplier" id="supplier" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">---</option>
                    <?php
                    $posts = get_field('course_providers');
                    if( $posts ): ?>
                        <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                            <option value="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </select>

                <select name="supplier_email" id="supplier_email" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">---</option>
                    <?php
                    $posts = get_field('course_providers');
                    if( $posts ): ?>
                        <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                            <option value="<?php the_field('email_address'); ?>"><?php the_field('email_address'); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </select>
```

I hope this can be done with jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things easier you could add the email address as a data attribute to the  tag for each provider title like so:

```
<select name="supplier" id="supplier" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">---</option>
                    <?php
                    $posts = get_field('course_providers');
                    if( $posts ): ?>
                        <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                            <option value="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-email="<?php the_field('email_address'); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </select>
```

Then in your jQuery you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#supplier').change(function() {
        var emailAddress = $('select#supplier').find(':selected').data('email');
    });
    // Do something with the var emailAddress on form submit here
});
```