# Dynamically populate Contact Form 7 dropdown field with content from ACF field

Tags: javascript, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

I have been using an old Wordpress contact form plugin (FastSecureContactForm) alongside some javescript someone built for me years ago to dynamically populate a field in the form with a dropdown list of file titles pulled from an ACF field. This has worked very well for me but I've rebuilt my website and am now using Contact Form 7 & wish to repeat this functionality.

The Javascript previously used referenced the ACF field from where it took the (multiple) track names as `track_name` and referenced the form field in FastSecureContactForm where the list of file names would be dynamically built as `si_contact_ex_field2_3` where the number 2 referenced Form 2 in the setup & the number 3 referenced extra field 3 (`ex_field3`) on the form. The part of the javascript relating to this function is as follows (I understand basic php but have no javascript knowledge):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var field_to_update = document.getElementById('si_contact_ex_field2_3');
field_to_update.innerHTML = '';

var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
elOptNew.text = 'Select'
elOptNew.value = 'Select';

field_to_update.add(elOptNew);

field_to_update.options[0].selected = true;

var track_names = document.getElementsByName('audioFileName');  

for (i=0; i<track_names.length; i++) {

    var track_name = track_names[i].innerHTML;

    var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
    elOptNew.text = track_name.replace("&amp;", "&");
    elOptNew.value = track_name;

    field_to_update.add(elOptNew); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE

}
```

What I'd like to know is:

A) How can I reference the dropdown field in the new form (built on Contact Form 7) and utilise the above javascript so that it is populated by the ACF field (as in the previous form). At the moment I have created a "Form Tag" like this `[select* menu-470 "Select" "Track A" "Track B" "Track C"]` but obviously the `"Track A" "Track B" "Track C"` part of the tag needs to be dynamically replaced by the multiple `track_name`s inputted into the ACF field.

B) Or if there's a better / simpler way to dynamically fill the dropdown field on the Contact Form 7 form I'd be most interested to know

Many thanks in advance for any help with this issue.

Phil

Comment: does this post help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779950/how-to-get-a-dynamic-dropdown-with-an-acf-relationship-field?rq=1 ??

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach that doesn't require any additional plugins.

Create your form like this:

```
[checkbox my-values data:my_possible_values]
[submit]
```

Then add this to your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function($n, $options, $args) {
  if (in_array('my_possible_values', $options)){
    
    // Assuming that my_acf_field is an ACF multi-select field
    $my_possible_values = get_field('my_acf_field');

    // turn $my_possible_values into an array
    // that looks like this: ['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3']
    return array_map(function($el) {
        return $el['value'];
    }, $my_possible_values);
  }
  return $n;
}, 10, 3);
```

Note: the `data` attribute can also be used in `[radio]` and `[select]` fields.

See it in action here: https://bdwm.be/dynamically-populate-a-contact-form-7-dropdown-list-or-any-other-input-field/

Comment: Best Solution! Thanks. :)

Comment: this should be marked as correct

Answer (score 1):

The [Smart Grid-layout Design for cf7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extension plugin has a dynamic dropdown field tag designed to solve this type of issues.

You would convert your select tag into a dynamic one,

```
[dynamic_select dynamic_select-353 "source:filter"]
```

the dynamic dropdown has 3 potential source of data, an existing taxonomy, a post type or a custom filter.  Use the custom filter source to programmatically pull the data from your ACF field and populate your dropdown field usinf this filter,

```
add_filter( 'cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options','dynamic_select_353_dynamic_options',10,3);
/**
* Filter dropdown options for dynamic drodpwn list of taxonomy terms.
* @param mixed $options the opttion to filter.
* @param string $name the field name being populated.
* @param string $cf7_key  the form unique key.
* @return mixed $options return either an array of <option value>=><option label> pairs or a html string of option elements which can be grouped if required.
*/
function dynamic_select_353_dynamic_options($options, $name, $cf7_key){
  $data = ... //fetch your data from your ACF field.
  foreach($data as $label=>$value){
    $options += '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$label.'</option>';
  }
  return $options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this & apologies for taking ages to reply (been tied up with a family matter) - have installed the plugin and looks good. One question if that's OK - when  you say @options is the option to filter, I presume that means the ACF field I'm pulling the info from - so would be something like `$options = get_field( 'audioFileName' );` - am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: not really, if you read the code above, options are an array of values and labels.  Read up about HTML select fields to see how they are constructed to better understand this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, will investigate what you suggested and hopefully resolve the issue on weekend.

Comment: Hi `@Aurovrata` I'm still trying to get this to work and am still not sure what is meant by `@param mixed $options the opttion to filter` - I understand that the variable `$name` is defined the name of the form field (in this instance `dynamic_select-353`) and `$cf7_key` is the unique number of the form but I don't understand how to define the variable `@options`- would you be able to explain that to me? Many thanks Phil

Comment: look at this [select dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) example html construct.  The filter function expect you to return an html string that represensts each value/label pair options you want to appear in your select dropdpwn.

Comment: alternatively, you can return an array of value/label pairs `[value1=>label1,value2=>label2...]`

Comment: Are you saying that I don't need to define the variable `@options` in the first place and that the result is returned as an array which can be accessed via `@options`? Sorry my knowledge is a little basic (but very much appreciate your help!)

Comment: `$options` is the variable you can filter in your custom function.  You can read more about how to filter variables in [WordPress Hooks](https://wpshout.com/wordpress-hooks-actions-filters-work/)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is coming here trying to dynamically populate a dropdown and realize that the value field is the same as the text that shows in the dropdown, and you instead want a value to be something different like an ID.

Then you can use the code below:

```
function populateBusinessesDropdown( array $tag ) {

    if ( $tag['name'] !== 'complaint-business' ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    $saved_businesses = [] // Add code to get your array of items here

    foreach ( $saved_businesses as $key => $business_info ) {

        $tag['raw_values'][] = $business_info['name'];
        $tag['values'][]     = $business_info['id'];
        $tag['labels'][]     = $business_info['name'];
    }

    $tag['raw_values'][] = 'Other';
    $tag['values'][]     = 0;
    $tag['labels'][]     = 'Other';

    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'populateBusinessesDropdown', 10 );
```